# Editplus replace lowercase case with uppercase

Tags: regex, editplus

I use Editplus to find replace values. I have String in the for abc_xyz. Is there way to convert it to abcXyz (camel case) using editplus regular expression and find replace functionality?

Comment: Short answer is no, unless your editor provides a function to convert letters into uppercase.

Answer (score 3):

The following works in Edit Plus 3.70.

Enter or check the following in the replace dialog.

- Find what: **(\w+)_([[:lower:]]{1})(\w*)**
- Replace with: **\1\U\2\E\3**
- Case sensitive: unchecked
- Regular expression: checked
- Support \U \L \E: checked

This works fine for the example given.

If you have a variable such as has_three_words then running the replace twice will convert the variable to hasThreeWords.

Comment: **Support \U \L \E**

Check this option to change case with \U \L \E escape sequences. 

\U changes to upper case until \E, and \L changes to lower case until \E.

Answer (score 1):

EditPlus 4.3;

> CTRL + U (Uppercase)
>
> CTRL + L (Lowercase)